# Merge graph lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

i am using python to model a surface and currently have a code which plots radially growing circles at random points. the next step is to "merge" these circles when/if the edges collide on the graph, ive done some searching but can't find any help on the topic.

```
from pylab import *
import random

A = 200

def Nuc_pos(N): #function to determine nucleation positions
    xy=[]
    xy=[]
    fail=[]
    success=[]
    
    for i in range(N):
        if random.random() > 0.1:
            fail.append(1)
        else:
            success.append(1)
    for k in range(len(success)):
        Nx = random.randint(1,A-1)
        Ny = random.randint(1,A-1)
        if [Nx, Ny] not in xy:
            xy.append([Nx, Ny])
    
    return np.array(xy), len(xy)

nuc_positions, nuc_number = Nuc_pos(100) #calling the nucleations for 100 runs

nucx = nuc_positions[:,0]
nucy = nuc_positions[:,1]

r = [2]
radiiList = [r]  #first radis list, with the first time=0 already set

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
x_circ = np.cos(theta)
y_circ = np.sin(theta)

def Growth(x, y):
    for t in range(1, 10):
  #first throw dice to see if new circle is created
      if random.random() < 0.6:
          radiiList.append([2]) #append a second r list
  #go through all r lists in radiiList and append radius at time t. 
      for r in radiiList:
    #r.append(2*(t+1))
        r.append(2*(len(r)+1))
  
        plt.figure(t)
      for r in radiiList:
          for k in range(len(nucx)):
            plt.plot(r[-1]*x_circ+x[k], r[-1]*y_circ+y[k], 'k')
            xlim(0,A)
            ylim(0,A)
    return plt.show()

print(Growth(nucx, nucy))
```

if its possible, i only want to be combining circles of the same radius.

Comment: Your question is not super clear without any kind of visualization. But my assumption is this is going to require some sort of clustering algorithm.